# Dispose data flutter

Tags: flutter, api

I am fetching data from API every second, the goal is to make the information realtime as much as possible. I want to properly dispose of the old data whenever I fetch new data.

```
  Future<List<Orders>> getStudentList() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("${Env.URL_PREFIX}/order_list.php"));
    final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    List<Orders> students = items.map<Orders>((json) {
      return Orders.fromJson(json);
    }).toList();
    print(students);
    return students;
  }



  setUpTimedFetch() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 1000), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        orders = getStudentList();
      });
    });
  }
```

How do I efficiently do this?

Answer (score 0):

There's not that much more you can do to make it more effecient, unless you're able to change the API to a streamed API (server-sent events, websocket, HTTP/2 streams, ...)

I did notice that you're not `await`ing the `getStudentList()`;.

Another solution would be to create a `Stream<List<Order>>` and use a `StreamBuilder`.

```
Future<List<Orders>> getStudentList() async {
  final response =
      await http.get(Uri.parse("${Env.URL_PREFIX}/order_list.php"));
  final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  List<Orders> students = items.map<Orders>((json) {
    return Orders.fromJson(json);
  }).toList();
  return students;
}

Stream<List<Orders>> createStudentListStream() {
  return Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (count) async {
    return getStudentList();
  }).asyncMap((future) async => await future);
}
```

Then you can use a `SteamBuilder` in your UI.

```
StreamBuilder<List<Orders>>(
  stream: createStudentListStream(),
  builder: (_, snapshot) {
    if(!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
    List<Orders> orders = snapshot.data;
    // build UI with orders
  }
),
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. I just want one clarification. Does this method mean the old data will not be in memory? I initially thought the data will still be in memory that is why I wanted to dispose it

Comment: No, Flutter takes care of that. It should get garbage collected. Both in your initial way as well as with StreamBuilder. You can always attach the devtools in your IDE and inspect the memory heap

Comment: That is great. Thanks for the feedback. I will use devtools.